# Error Phpmyadmin

Tags: ubuntu, php, phpmyadmin

i have this problem after updating ubuntu. It asked me if I wanted to update the configuration that it already had, and I said no. phpmyadmin was working correctly before the upgrade.

If anyone knows the error, and how to solve it, I would appreciate it.

Version of php 7.3 on ubuntu 18.04.

Thank you very much.

Error:

`PHP Warning:  require_once(Symfony/Polyfill/Apcu/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Cache/autoload.php on line 6`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a fix (also Ubuntu 18.04), I downgraded the package `php-symfony-polyfill-apcu` back to 1.6.0-2. It appears the version that was upgraded no longer includes all the same files, including the `'Symfony/Polyfill/Apcu/autoload.php'` file that is causing the issue here.

Comment: Hi thwaller, thank you very much for your reply. I was able to perfectly solve the problem posed.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I had to reinstall phpmyadmin to fix the problem. Same Ubuntu server 18.04.

```
sudo apt remove phpmyadmin
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phpmyadmin/ppa
sudo apt install phpmyadmin
```

Comment: Maybe this was https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=980375